# What library or framework does the remaining character counts for comments?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, character-limit, technology

Based on [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

What does Stack Exchange use to calculate the remaining character counts for comments? Do they use jquery, websockets, or something entirely different doing the comment real-time character counter?

Comment: The code behind the site isn't simple, but the character counter is obviously client-side, and the dev tools of any modern browser make it easy to see that jQuery is used.

Comment: It's all client side, so just look at the source and see for yourself...

Comment: I did look at the source, and it was somewhat a maze, especially if you account for the possibility of .net minification and bundling making another client side framework very difficult to pick out of the sources.

Comment: @Maslow they obfuscate and minimize the JS code, don't think it got anything to do with .NET, just standard procedure.

Comment: so 3 downvotes without clear comments on why this is a bad question? Is it really just because I could potentially figure this out given enough time and studying their code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using custom made jQuery plugin, written by one of the Stack Exchange developers.

The code is public anyway, so I'll quote it here for convenience:

```javascript
charCounter: function(a) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var c = a.target ? $(a.target) : $(this).parents("form").find("span.text-counter"),
        f = this;
        $(this).bind("blur focus keyup paste charCounterUpdate", d.DelayedReaction(function() {
            var d = a.min,
            h = a.max,
            l = a.setIsValid || function() {},
            k = f.value ? f.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").length: 0,
            j = k > 0.8 * h ? "supernova": k > 0.6 * h ? "hot": k > 0.4 * h ? "warm": "cool",
            n = "";
            0 == k ? 0 == d ? (n = function(a) {
                return 1 == a.max ? "enter up to " + a.max + " charcter": "enter up to " + a.max + " charcters"
            } ({
                max: h
            }), l(!0)) : (n = function(a) {
                return 1 == a.min ? "enter at least " + a.min + " character": "enter at least " + a.min + " characters"
            } ({
                min: d
            }), l(!1)) : k < d ? (n = d - k + " more to go...", l(!1)) : (d = h - k, n = 0 <= d ? function(a) {
                return 1 == a.count ? a.count + " character left": a.count + " characters left"
            } ({
                count: d
            }) : function(a) {
                return 1 == a.count ? "too long by " + a.count + " character": "too long by " + a.count + " characters"
            } ({
                count: Math.abs(d)
            }), l(k <= h));
            c.text(n);
            c.hasClass(j) || c.removeClass("supernova hot warm cool").addClass(j)
        }, 100, {
            sliding: !0
        }).trigger)
    })
},
```

Comment: @RobW That URL is "Site not found" now.

Comment: @ChrisW please flag Rob's comment as "no longer needed", and it might get deleted before Rob gets back to check. (comments can't be edited anyway)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance I figure that Rob can delete his own comment after he's seen mine, and optionally add a new URL if there is one.

Comment: @Chris sure, but Rob wasn't around for a while. Otherwise I wouldn't ping you with that. :-)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Rob was "Last seen 2 days ago" on StackOverflow , maybe he'll notice my @ within a few days days, but feel free to flag this yourself if you think it's useless to wait.

Comment: @ChrisW I don't see my original comment any more, and I now lack the context to fix the out-of-date comment. I can't even find it in https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/214259/timeline

Comment: dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/stub.js was the link

Comment: @Rob deleted comments leave no trace for non moderators. Nobody can know that they ever existed unless they saved a screenshot, or the page is archived somewhere.

Comment: This link works today: https://dev.sstatic.net/js/stub.js